# Determine if the solution can be optimally given using greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Most of the times the confusing fact is whether to go for an exhaustive search (dynamic programming or back tracking or brute force) to solve the problem or to go for the greedy approach.

I am not talking about using greedy to determine the best possible solution, I am talking about using greedy algorithm to find "the solution". I am trying to get some standard ways in which I can validate if the problem can be solved with greedy approach. Like Optimal substructure, memorization for dynamic programming. And not related any specific problem.

Are there any proof of induction I can do to decide if greedy approach will always produce the best solution?

Comment: It depends on the question/problem.

Comment: Certain problems sometimes tend to have more than one solution especially since certain problems have incredibly large search spaces. I think you need to provide more information on your problem first.

Comment: I am talking about a generic way to find if a problem can be solved using greedy. Say a standard 4-5 ways. I am asking this, since in many coding competitions like TopCoder, always its a matter of using exhaustive search or using the greedy.  In the same way we find time complexity (using recursion tree or using master theorem or using both), are there any theorm/method to identify it?

Comment: As mentioned in question, I am trying to get a generic way and not specific to a problem. What will be your reply if I asked how to find if the problem is solved using Dynamic Programming? The same way, are thre any way for greedy. I ve searched and came out more or less void.

Comment: There's a mathematical theory behind, but it's not that simple. Search for "matroid". Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Greedy_algorithms, read Theorems 1 and 2

Comment: This is something I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Haile You should probably present your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### In general

To prove that an optimization problem can be solved using a greedy algorithm, we need to prove that the problem has the following:

- **Optimal substructure property**: an optimal global solution contains the optimal solutions of all its subproblems.
- **Greedy choice property**: a *global* optimal solution can be obtained by greedily selecting a *locally* optimal choice.

---

### Example

> Let us consider the classical **activity selection problem**. We have a set *S* of *n* activities, each one with a start time `s[i]` and an end time `e[i]`. We want to choose a subset of S, such that the selection **maximizes the number of non overlapping events**.

[This problem can be solved using a greedy algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478733/1146303), but how can we **prove** that?

We need to show it exhibits:

- **Optimal substructure**

Consider a general activity *a* contained in a global optimal solution `S = {A', a, A''}`, where `S` is the global optimal solution, *a* is our little activity, and `A'` and `A''` are two subproblems of finding the activities *before* a and *after* a.

If the problem has the optimal substructure property, **the optimal solution for the subproblems `A'` and `A''` must be contained in the global optimal solution `S`**.

This is true, but why?

Suppose that the optimal solution for the subproblem `A'` is not in `S`. Then we could substitute the optimal for `A'`, say `S'`, in `A`, to obtain a new global optimal solution that is better than `S`. But `S` was the global optimal solution! Contradiction.

- **Greedy choice**:

We need to prove that our greedy choice (to select the activity that ends first) is correct.

Let `B` be a subproblem. Let *b* be the activity of the subproblem `B` that ends first, thus *b* is our (first) greedy choice. **We need to prove that *b* is included in some optimal solution for `B`**.

Let `X` be an optimal solution for the subproblem `B`. Let *x* be the activity in `X` that ends first.

1. If *b* = *x*, then *b* is in `X`, the optimal solution for `B`, and we have shown that the greedy choice is included in the optimal solution.
2. If *b* != *x*, surely we have that `end_time[b] < end_time[x]`.

   Since *b* was our greedy choice (i.e. the activity that ends first of all in the subproblem `B`), then we can substitute `x` with *b* in `X` to obtain another optimal solution: `X' = (X \ {x}) U {b}`. `X'` is optimal because it has the same number of activities of `X`, and `X` was optimal, and in this case, *b* is in `X'`, the optimal solution for `B`.

So our greedy choice `b` is included in some optimal solution for `B` in one case or the other.

---

### Matroids

Furthermore, there's a powerful mathematical theory that can be **in some case** used to mechanically prove that a particular problem can be solved with a greedy approach.

Briefly:

- One can define a particular combinatoric structure named **matroid**.
- Some smart man proved in the past that these **matroids have the Optimal substructure property and the Greedy choice property**.
- This means that you can run a greedy algorithm on your optimization problem, and it will find the optimal solution. You only need to **verify that your problem is defined on a matroid-like structure**.

Further information about this can be found [here](http://math.fau.edu/locke/Greedy.htm).